# Selecting last record in a huge table in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server

I have a table containing latitude and longitude of 2000+ cars. Position of each car is added to the table every minute, and now it has more than 200M records. In my application I want to get last position of each car. I use the following query:

```
SELECT TOP 1 * 
FROM position 
WHERE car_id = 20 
ORDER BY id DESC
```

But this query takes a long time (about 5 minutes). Is there a better way to query last position of each car?

Comment: `LIMIT 1` and SQL Server? Are you sure?

Comment: Have you set an INDEX on column id?

Comment: Sounds like you should profile the query execution plan to find the bottleneck, rather than just make guesses as to what might be faster.

Comment: `ROW_NUMBER()` is your friend here.

Comment: A solution would be to have a separate table which only logs the last position. And not the whole history. (maybe with a Trigger?)

Comment: Does this table have a primary key?

Comment: @Johan not the best solution normally, but at 2000 updates/min, it may be a better option. Since this is obviously an IoT scenario, whatever endpoint ingests the positions should be able to update another table *very* easily. If that table is in-memory, the cost would be negligible

Comment: @hpn What SQL Server version? Could you use in-memory tables, eg to hold the last position? Obviously this is an IoT scenario, how do you ingest positions? Could you do what Johan suggested?

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos That's what I thought indeed. When a simple query like the OP is using takes 5 minutes, there must be a lot of records, or the hardware/config is not capable (when indexes are properly set). So then you have to look for other solutions.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming table `position` has a primary key, you could select the `MAX([pk])` from the table, associated with each `car_id`.  See below example:

```
CREATE TABLE #Test
(
ID INT PRIMARY KEY
,car_id INT
,description VARCHAR(20)
)

INSERT #Test
VALUES
(1, 20, 'Chevy'),
(2, 20, 'Chevy'),
(3, 30, 'Ford'),
(4, 30, 'Ford'),
(5, 30, 'Ford'),
(6, 40, 'Audi'),
(7, 40, 'Audi'),
(8, 40, 'Audi')

SELECT
T.*
FROM #Test T
WHERE T.ID = (SELECT MAX(ID) FROM #Test WHERE car_id = T.car_id)
```

Results in the following:

```
| ID | car_id | description |
| 8  |   40   |    Audi     |
| 5  |   30   |    Ford     |
| 2  |   20   |    Chevy    |
```

Obviously, `description` would need to be replaced with `longitude` and `latitude` to meet your needs, but this approach should work nonetheless. Using `ORDER BY` in most cases slows down the query significantly, so any time you can avoid it is preferred.

Comment: It would be simpler to join with the subquery on car_ID

Comment: But then it would return every line in the table, not just the last record

Comment: No, it would do the same. This syntax is equivalent to joining #Test with `(SELECT MAX(ID) as ID FROM #Test group by car_id)` and will generate the same execution plan, eg `select #Test.* from #Test inner join ((SELECT car_id, MAX(ID) FROM #Test group by car_id`) x on x.id= #Test.id

Comment: I wouldn't try either query just like that on 200M rows though.

Comment: I see what you're saying now.  Seems like they both do the same thing though, since my `WHERE` clause is on the `ID`.  I don't have that much data to really test which one is faster though ;)